# Has many save cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a situation where I have hasMany relations between two objects. request data looks like this

```
array(
'Project' => array(
    'name' => 'Projekt Y',
    'main_contractor' => 'APOS - Zagreb',
    'main_contractor_id' => '188',
    'arhitect_id' => '20'
),
'ProjectAssociate' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'project_role_id' => '1',
        'Person' => array(
            'input' => 'First name, last name',
            'firm_id' => ''
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'project_role_id' => '1',
        'Person' => array(
            'input' => '',
            'firm_id' => ''
        )
    )
)
```

)

The problem is, that I can not save this data because validation does not allow Person.input to be empty. Is there a way to cancel the save proces only for ProjectAssociate.1? I want to successfully save the rest of the data

Answer (score 1):

Try to unbind your **ProjectAssociate** model

```
// Let's remove the hasMany...
$this->Project->unbindModel(
    array('hasMany' => array('ProjectAssociate'))
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: I don't want to unbid, because that would prevent me from saving any additonal ProjectAssociates.

Comment: As I understand you have Person object. You can try to unbind only Person model.

Comment: The same answer as before, then I cant save any additional people. 
Unbind will probably be my last resort, but its not a good solution

Comment: Or you can try to disable  Person.input rule. $this->validator()->remove($field); http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Comment: but then again, I will have a record in my database with a empty input?

Comment: Do you use $Model->saveMany() ? ( saveAll() )

Comment: yes. I use saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true)